# What does the "?" (question mark) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to comment out code that I used from a tutorial but haven't actually seen a ?-mark used in JavaScript...

This is a small part of the code below:

```
this.year = (isNaN(year) || year == null) ? calCurrent.getFullYear() : year;
```

Comment: See "ternary operator" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you are referring to is the ternary operator which is an inline conditional statement. To illustrate:

```
 this.year = (isNaN(year) || year == null) ? calCurrent.getFullYear() : year;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(isNaN(year) || year == null){
       this.year=calCurrent.getFullYear()
 }
 else{
        this.year=year;
 }
```